# Careers - link to (or import from) Google Scholar

Tags: feature-request, jobs, google

[Google Scholar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Scholar) is another "identity and information source". It'd be convenient to be able to point to an account there to pull in publications in a structured way.